# SQL many to many query returns false

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I am trying to figure out how to do many to many sql queries and have hit an issue.

My db structure is:

```
projects_users_roles: project_id, user_id, role_id
user_roles: id, name
projects: id, name, user_id
```

So in my query I would like to select all projects for user_id=23 and what role name they have been assigned on that project in projects_users_roles

I thought I had it but its returning FALSE

```
$query = "
SELECT p.name AS project_name
, r.name AS role_name
FROM projects AS p
JOIN projects_users_roles AS a
   ON a.project_id = p.id
JOIN users_roles AS role
   ON role.id = a.role_id WHERE a.user_id = 23
";
$result = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: `FALSE` generally means an error occurred. Try `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` and add the output to your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be that the alias `r` is never defined? Your code sample shows `r.name` in the `SELECT` instead of `role.name`.

```
$query = "
SELECT p.name AS project_name
, role.name AS role_name
FROM projects AS p
JOIN projects_users_roles AS a
   ON a.project_id = p.id
JOIN users_roles AS role
   ON role.id = a.role_id WHERE a.user_id = 23
";
$result = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an alias that doesn't exists on your query, `r`:

```
SELECT  p.name AS project_name, 
        r.name AS role_name
FROM projects AS p
INNER JOIN projects_users_roles AS a
   ON a.project_id = p.id
INNER JOIN users_roles AS r
   ON r.id = a.role_id 
WHERE a.user_id = 23
```

And, maybe `role` is a reserved word on MySQL.